# General formulas for $\cos \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\theta_{i}\right)$ and $\sin \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\theta_{i}\right)$?

Tags: trigonometry

Can someone tell me the general formula for the cosine and sine of a sum of more than two angles?
$$\cos \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\theta_{i}\right)=? \qquad \sin \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\theta_{i}\right)=?$$

I can't find it anywhere!

Comment: I think there is no clear general formula

Comment: Even when all $\theta_i$ are equal it is slightly complicated.

Comment: I guess it have no beautiful form. There will be some trigonometric polynomial with $2^{n}$ parts. You can consider $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \theta_{i} + \theta_{n}$. Use formula for $2$ angles and imagine what will be.

Comment: @DavidPeterson using complex representation , it will have short form. But for different $\theta$ the same trick isn't allowed.

Comment: @DavidPeterson slightly complicated will do. It's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities),
$$
\cos\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\theta_{i}\Bigr)=\sum_{\substack{0\le k\le n\\k\text{ even}}}(-1)^{k/2}\sum_{\substack{A\subset\{1,\dots,n\}\\|A|=k}}\Bigl(\prod_{i\in A}\sin\theta_i\prod_{i\notin A}\cos\theta_i\Bigr)
$$

Comment: That'll do. Thanks!